# Securing server to server api calls

Tags: http, security, ssl, https

My servers send requests to eachother with sensitive data.

**Example:**
`POST http://s1.abcd.com:8080/?sensitive_data=data`

It's server-to-server, not client-to-server
Do i have to use the `https` protocol?

Comment: Yes. Is there anything more to the question?

Comment: For the fuller version, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227020/is-https-required-for-local-network-server-to-server-communication. This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but is appropriate (and answered) for Security.SE.

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you.